# get file size and append to new column of CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Python 2.4
For my example I have a 2 column csv file

Eg:

```
HOST, FILE
server1, /path/to/file1
server2, /path/to/file2
server3, /path/to/file3
```

I would like to get the file size of the object at PATH for each row in the csv FILE, then add that value to the csv FILE on a new column.
Making it:

```
 HOST, PATH, FILESIZE
 server1, /path/to/file1, 6546542
 server2, /path/to/file2, 46546343
 server3, /path/to/file3, 87523
```

Ive tried a couple methods but havnt had much success.

The code below executes fileSizeCmd (du -b) on the PATH and outputs the filezie correctly, but I havnt figured out how to use the data to add to the csv FILE

```
 import datetime
 import csv
 import os, time
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 fileSizeCmd = "du -b"
 SP = " "

 # Try to get disk size and append to another row after entry above
 #st = os.stat(row[3])
 #except IOError:
 #print "failed to get information about", file
 #else:
 #print "file size:", st[ST_SIZE]
 #print "file modified:", time.asctime(time.localtime(st[ST_MTIME]))

 incsv = open('my_list.csv', 'rb')
 try:
     reader = csv.reader(incsv)
     outcsv = open('results/results_' + now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") + '.csv', 'wb')
     try:
         writer = csv.writer(outcsv)

         for row in reader:
         p = Popen(fileSizeCmd + SP + row[1], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
         stdout, empty = p.communicate()


         print 'Command: %s\nOutput: %s\n' % (fileSizeCmd + SP + row[1], stdout)

         #  Results in bytes example
         #
         #  Output:
         #  8589935104      /path/to/file
         #

     #  Write 8589935104 to new column of csv FILE

   finally:
      outcsv.close()

 finally:
incsv.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch w/o error handling:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import os

filename = "sample.csv"
# localhost, 01.html.bak
# localhost, 01.htmlbak
# ...

def filesize(filename):
    # no need to shell out for filesize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size

with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle)
    # result is written to sample.csv.updated.csv
    writer = csv.writer(open('%s.updated.csv' % filename, 'w'))
    for row in reader:
        # need to strip filename, just in case
        writer.writerow(row + [ filesize(row[1].strip()) ])

# result
# localhost, 01.html.bak,10021
# localhost, 01.htmlbak,218982
# ...
```

Comment: I cant seem to get that to work with 2.4. I think Ive converted your with statements right but Im still not having much luck

Comment: @miku I got this working. Thanks.  It does fail if a file doesnt exist, however

Comment: adding `    if os.path.exists(filename):` seems to resolve my issue where file might not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can

1) read the cvs content into a list of tuple of (server, filename)

2) collect the file size for each element of this list

3) package the result into another tuple (server, filename, filesize) into another list ('result')

4) write out the result to new file

Answer (score 0):

First, getting file size is a lot easier than using `subprocess` (see [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat)):

```
>>> os.stat('/tmp/file').st_size
100
```

Second, you're on the right track with your `writer` object writing to a different file, but you just need to add a column to the `row` lists you're getting back from the `reader` and then feed them to `writerow` on the `writer` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer)).  Something like this:

```
>>> writerfp = open('out.csv', 'w')
>>> writer = csv.writer(writerfp)
>>> for row in csv.reader(open('in.csv', 'r')):
...     row.append('column')
...     writer.writerow(row)
...
>>> writerfp.close()
```